# Python Requests: Selecting a form for login

Tags: python, request, mechanize

I've been successfully scraping a website using mechanize, but I've had some problems with the page.open getting stuck (and not giving a timeout error) so I'd like to try and perform the same scrape with Requests. However, I can't figure out how to select a form to enter my login credentials. Here is the working code in mechanize:

```
# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
br.set_proxies({"https": "198.102.28.100:7808", "http": "54.235.92.109:8080"})

# Open Login Page
br.open("https://example.com/login/Signin?")
br.select_form(name="signinForm_0")
br["loginEmail"] = "username"
br["loginPassword"] = 'password'
br.method = "POST"
br.submit()

#Open Page
URL = 'https://example.com'
br.open(URL, timeout=5.0)
```

I'm unsure how to replicate the br.select_form functionality using Python Requets. Does anyone have any ideas or experience doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If I not wrong, [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) is similar to Mechanize, but not Requests. Requests is used mostly to HTTP. Requests is similar to [urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) or [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) but it is better. You can send request (GET or POST) and read html file from server but you need other modules to get some element on page - [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#), [lxml](http://lxml.de), [pyQuery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery)